# Check if a entity already exists in the database using Symfony and Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

So, here's my situation. I've 3 tables, `tag`, `product` and `tag_product`, which is created from annotations of a "many-to-many" relationship between `tag` and `product`, i.e. a `tag` can be associated with many products and a product can have many tags associated with it.

Now, I'm using a data transformer to transform the `Tag` objects to a string composed of the tags separate by commas whenever the user wants to edit a product.

In the `Tag` entity I've a primary key, an id, and a unique field, the name of the tag. I don't essentially want to have two tags with the same name.

My problem is that I don't know how to access the "new" tags chosen by the user when the form has been submitted to update the product. Is there a way to do it? Accessing the request may only be useful to access the input string of tags, but not the `Tag` objects created from that string in the data transformer.

I could also pass the current `$product` object to `buildForm`, which would pass it to the data transformer mentioned above, but this doesn't seem a good solution, when an object is passed around (at least to me). Also I would need to create another entity manager from the data transformer and do things that a data transformer shouldn't do.

Any better ideas?

**Edit**

I've just thought that maybe I could just check when inserting the tag in the `ArrayCollection` of the product if that same `ArrayCollection` already contains a tag with the same name of the being inserted tag, but since I don't know if that collection will be already filled with the current tags or not, at that moment...

**Edit 2**

The solution in the previous edit doesn't work for me, I guess, again, because that array collection is empty when the new tag is inserted...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is best practice, but what I have done in the past is use the following `ModelTransformer`

```
// ArrayCollection of tags to string
function ($tags)
{
    if ($tags === null)
        return '';

    return implode(',', array_map(function($tag){
        return $tag->getName();
    }, $tags->toArray()));
}

// string to ArrayCollection of tags
function ($string)
{
    $tags = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    if ($string === '' || $string === null)
        return $tags;

    $array = explode(',', $string);
    foreach ($array as $tagName) {
        $tag = $this->em
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Tag')
            ->findOrCreateByName($tagName);
        $tags->add($tag);
    }

    return $tags;
}
```

Where the key actually is the `findOrCreateByName()` method in the `TagRepository`

```
public function findOrCreateByName($name)
{
    $name = trim($name);

    $tag = self::findOneBy(['name' => $name]);

    if ($tag === null) {
        $tag = new Tag;
        $tag->setName($name);
    }

    return $tag;
}
```

Comment: So this is similar to my idea of checking in the transformer... at the end if I don't find a solution to do it in the controller, which is the place, I think, I should do it, I will go with this option... if I could access somehow the data after all transformations of the submitted form, I could do it in the controller...

Comment: I don't think the Controller is the right place for this. It should be agnostic about the Models, meaning not know/care if they already exist, this is clearly part of the Model/Repository.

Comment: Yes, but that work of accessing and modifying the data of the db using either repositories or not is usually done (explicitly or not, i.e. by calling a service) in the controller...

Comment: True. Happy to hear if you find another/cleaner solution